# Can I use the syntax parent.Childs.create multiple times, when declaring a parent and two child records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

```
customer=Customer.new #create a new Customer object
customer.id =1000+i #Id needs to be set first because otherwise its automatically set
customer.update_attributes(
    :fname=>'mike',
    :lname=>'hancock',
    :Year=>1998,
    :Model=>'buick',
    :Engine=>'4 liter',
    :vinnum=>'h920129801298',
    :signupdate=>"#{Date.today}",
    :password=>'fguygfyed',
)
    contact=Contact.create(
        :customer_id=>customer.id, #set the foreign primary key
        :contactmethod=>4567894561,
        :contacttype=>"sms",
        :dateadded=>"#{Date.today}",
    )
    customer.Contacts.create(
        :contactmethod=> 4657894564,
        :contacttype=> 'email',
        :dateadded=> "#{Date.today}",
    )
    i+=1
end
```

This code works.  However, if instead of

contact=Contact.create(
        :customer_id=>customer.id, #set the foreign primary key

I just wrote customer.Contacts.create like I wrote at the end then the code fails.  Why is it that I can only have one instance of customer.Contacts.create and for the other I have to explicitly declare the customer.id?

Answer (score 0):

Method names are almost always declared as all lower-case. This doesn't seem to be valid.

What you probably intend is:

```
customer.contacts.create(...)
```

Comment: My code I gave you works but I will test your code to see if it works.  Maybe there is some other part of my code that you want to see to understand my issue?

Comment: sorry tadman, just tested your code and it produced an error.

Comment: You've got a very irregular mix of upper-case and lower-case columns, so if you've declared `has_many :Contacts` it might work as you intend. However, this is extremely non-standard and should be avoided, lower-case names are the convention.

Comment: If it's failing, you will need to be more specific. What error does it produce? An exception?

Comment: rake aborted!undefined method `contacts' for #<Customer:0x4be0820>

Comment: I just change all the has_many and belongs_to to lowercase and then I tried the code you laid out and it doesn't work.  The first letter of the database names are capitalized.  Is that non-standard too?  This was the error: rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `contacts' for main:Object

Comment: In the Rails world, table names, column names, and method names are lower-case only and are underscored like `my_thing`. Classes are capitalized like `MyThing`. Constants are all-caps like `MY_CONST`. You can defy these conventions but it makes your application needlessly non-standard and more confusing for anyone who has to maintain it. You should have `has_many :contacts` for table name `contacts` for model `Contact`.  Remember `create!` will raise an exception with a more specific error if you're curious why something's not being saved.